# c# MemoryMappedFile Does the operating system allow a single file to be accessed by multiple ViewAccessor

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

As you can see I am creating multiple instances of ViewAccessor because it is within a parallel loop... The goal is to write chunks at specific offset paralelly. The problem is it is not writing at specific offsets but random.

```
String filePath = @"C:\\Users\\Quarx\\Desktop\\book.txt";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
int length = (int)fileInfo.Length;
MemoryMappedFile mf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, "mapp1");
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mf.CreateViewAccessor();
MemoryMappedFile mf2 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\\Users\\Quarx\\Desktop\\parabob.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, "log-map", length);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor2 = null;
Parallel.For(0, totalChunks, (i) =>
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int readBytes = accessor.ReadArray(1024 * i, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    accessor.Flush();
    accessor2 = mf2.CreateViewAccessor(1024 * i, readBytes);
    accessor2.WriteArray(0, bytes, 0, readBytes);
    accessor2.Flush();
}

);
accessor2.Dispose();
accessor.Dispose();
```

Comment: If your objective is to copy a file at maximum efficiency then this not the best, just use File.Copy as it will use native calls to create the copy.

Comment: Use `var accessor2 = mf2.CreateViewAccessor(...);` so the variable is not shared between threads.